# Data Transfer Between SQL Server and SQL Server Compact

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I am using VS 2008 with SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server Compact Framework 3.5

- I have mobile devices(They have Window Ce 6.0 os).
- I installed my program to windows ce devices
- I am using .sdf database in device.
- `.SDF` and `.MDF` database schema are the same

Workers use this devices out of company and save data.

When they arrive at the company I have to save the data from their `.sdf` files into a SQL Server instance.

I do it like this:

```
public void TransferData()
{
   SqlCeCommand tempcecommand=new SqlCeCommand("select * from Customer",SDFConnection);
   SqlCeDataReader tempcereader=tempcecommand.ExecuteReader();

   SqlCommand tempmscommad=new SqlCommand("",MDFConnection);

   while(tempcereader.Read())
   {
      tempcommandtext = String.Format("insert into Customer (Column1,Column2) values       ('{0}','{1}')",tempcereader["Column1"],tempcereader["Column2"] ;

      tempmscommand.CommandText = tempmscommand;
      tempmscommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Is there an easier way to transfer the data from the `.sdf` file into the SQL Server instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first approach could be

```
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (Column1, Column2) VALUES (@col1, @col2)"
SqlCommand tempmscommad=new SqlCommand(cmdText,MDFConnection);
tempmscommad.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", "");
tempmscommad.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", "");
while(tempcereader.Read())
{
    tempmscommad.Parameters["col1"].Value = tempcereader["Column1"].ToString();
    tempmscommad.Parameters["col2"].Value = tempcereader["Column2"].ToString();
    tempmscommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This will still loop over your CE data, but remove the string formatting inside the loop and use a more secure parameterized query. However, this will require to execute a command for each record to be inserted.

If you are **ABSOLUTELY** sure that your values could not be tampered by your user when importing, then it is possible to take advantage of the multiinsert capabilities of Sql Insert

**BE AWARE** - This way is not really recommended because it use string concatenation, a very dangerous practice when dealing with database commands.
You NEED to be certain that your [input values are SANITIZED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

```
StringBuilder cmdText = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (Column1, Column2) VALUES ");
while(tempcereader.Read())
{
    cmdText.AppendFormat("('{0}', '{1}'),", 
            tempcereader["Column1"].ToString(),
            tempcereader["Column2"].ToString())
}
// remove the last comma
cmdText.Length -= 1;

// Just execute one single command 
SqlCommand tempmscommad=new SqlCommand(cmdText.ToString(),MDFConnection);
tempmscommad.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Finally, **`THE BEST OPTION`** should be to use the class [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I have no way to test it because I don't have a SqlCE data available, but, giving the fact that the [WriteToServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method accepts an IDataReader instance I suppose that it should work also with an SqlCeDataReader

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(MDFConnection))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "CUSTOMER";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(tempcereader);
}
```

Please test it....